# Transforming one record into multiple records

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If the format of the input is

```
(x1,(a,b,c,List(key1, key2))
(x2,(a,b,c,List(key3))
```

and I would like to achieve this output

```
(key1,(a,b,c,x1))
(key2,(a,b,c,x1))
(key3,(a,b,c,x2))
```

---

Here is the code:

```
var hashtags = joined_d.map(x => (x._1, (x._2._1._1, x._2._2, x._2._1._4, getHashTags(x._2._1._4))))

var hashtags_keys = hashtags.map(x => if(x._2._4.size == 0) (x._1, (x._2._1, x._2._2, x._2._3, 0)) else
x._2._4.map(y => (y, (x._2._1, x._2._2, x._2._3, 1))))
```

The function getHashTags() returns a list. If the list is not empty, we want to use each elements in the list as the new key. How should i work around this issue?

Comment: try using `flatMap` instead of map transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `rdd` created as:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
    Seq(
        ("x1",("a","b","c",List("key1", "key2"))), 
        ("x2", ("a", "b", "c", List("key3")))
    )
)
```

You can use `flatMap` like this:

```
rdd.flatMap{ case (x, (a, b, c, list)) => list.map(k => (k, (a, b, c, x))) }.collect
// res12: Array[(String, (String, String, String, String))] = 
//        Array((key1,(a,b,c,x1)), 
//              (key2,(a,b,c,x1)), 
//              (key3,(a,b,c,x2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("x1", ("a", "b", "c", List("key1", "key2"))),
  ("x2", ("a", "b", "c", List("key3")))
))

val rdd2 = rdd.flatMap{
  case (x, (a, b, c, l)) => l.map( (_, (a, b, c, x) ) )
}

rdd2.collect
// res1: Array[(String, (String, String, String, String))] = Array((key1,(a,b,c,x1)), (key2,(a,b,c,x1)), (key3,(a,b,c,x2)))
```